# Perform pagination on search results using JSTL tag or JQuery

Tags: jquery, pagination, jstl

So i want to do pagination on my search resuts. E.g. I have 1000 records and want to divide it in 100 pages with links at bottom as 1,2,3, ... 100 etc. ??

What is the best way to do it ?

I want to do the same using non-greedy approach

Comment: Is your search result going to be displayed in table format? If so check if [datatables](https://datatables.net/) plugin suites your need.

Comment: Yes it is to be displayed in table format

Comment: Then did u check the datatables plugin from my previous comment. It is very versatile. You can even directly give a url in the plug in code to fetch data from and display in pagenation.

Comment: What are the steps do i need to download it ?

Comment: Just include jquery and datatables js files in your page. Then follow the examples in datatables documentation to do your pagenation stuff.